# VaadinService.getCurrent() is null

Tags: vaadin7

All of a sudden the VaadinService.getCurrent() and JavaScript.getCurrent() are turning out to be null. I use the former to figure out the base directory to load a JS file. Any one can help me figure out why?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue anymore as it was found that the VaadinService.getCurrent() was being called inside a thread thus:

```
access(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        VaadinService.getCurrent();
}});
```

Comment: I advise you accept your answer. So others can see that this problem is solved.

Comment: hi, I need to get the base path from a different thread and looks like `VaadinService.getCurrent().getBaseDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` is not safe to use , what should be the alternative ?